# Facebook "Like Box" Does Not Show - Requires To Login To Show Profile Pictures of Others Who liked

Tags: profile, facebook-likebox, image

Pretty much what the title says - I want the facebook "Like" plugin to show regardless if you are logged in or logged out of facebook.

The plugin should show the facebook faces and likes but will ONLY show if you are logged into facebook.

If you are logged out... it shows "Login To See This Content" and below it.. It doesn't show profile pictures or "likes" for my plugin, it's just empty.

Here is my site - http://www.goodguyhobbies.com/

Your help would be appreciated! Thanks!!

facebook likebox

Answer (score 0):

Check the page you're pointing the Like Box to isn't restricted demographically (e.g. to specific countries or age ranges) - if it is the Like Box won't work for users who don't meet those restrictions, and also won't work for users who are logged out.

This is the same for API access to the page, you can only do so behalf of a user who can see the page on facebook.com